# How to set proxy for Chrome browser in selenium using Java code

Tags: java, selenium, proxy

I am trying to run my selenium java code to test a webpage. But webpage is not loading because of network restrictions. When I set the proxy manually and hit the url in browser it works fine. Now I need to pass those proxy setting while running the selenium code. Please help me on this.

I tried below code, but still it shows the same error:

```
Proxy p=new Proxy();


// Set HTTP Port to 7777
p.setHttpProxy("www.abc.com:8080");

// Create desired Capability object
DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();

// Pass proxy object p
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, p);

// Open  firefox browser
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

Comment: Passing a Capabilities object to the ChromeDriver() constructor is deprecated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue is resolved with below code -

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(); 
proxy.setHttpProxy("yoururl:portno"); 
proxy.setSslProxy("yoururl:portno"); 

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome(); 
capabilities.setCapability("proxy", proxy); 

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
options.addArguments("start-maximized"); 

capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options); 

driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: Hi @Praveen Medipally, I am getting "This site can’t be reached" error in browser with above code. I am having user id and password for my proxy server. I just injected it in my url like http://user:pwd@proxy:port. Is above code still working for you?

Comment: Passing a Capabilities object to the ChromeDriver() constructor is deprecated.

Answer (score 11):

Passing a Capabilities object to the ChromeDriver() constructor is deprecated. One way to use a proxy is this:

```
String proxy = "127.0.0.1:5000";
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions().addArguments("--proxy-server=http://" + proxy);
WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 8):

Passing a Capabilities object to the ChromeDriver() constructor is `deprecated`. You can find new official doc [here](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities).

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setAutodetect(false);
proxy.setHttpProxy("http_proxy-url:port"); 
proxy.setSslProxy("https_proxy-url:port");
proxy.setNoProxy("no_proxy-var");

chromeOptions.setCapability("proxy", proxy); 
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: tried in selenium 4 and gave bad proxy on purpose and it still connects to website :(.

Answer (score 4):

```
DesiredCapabilities dc;
dc = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();              
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "9090");
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "9090");                      
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
dc.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
driver = new ChromeDriver(dc);
```

Comment: Hi Barney, thanks for the response. But when I tried to implement the above code, still it shows me same error - "This site can't be reached"

Comment: Passing a Capabilities object to the ChromeDriver() constructor is deprecated.

Comment: tried in selenium 4 @Barney and with bad ip address and for some reason it still hits the website :(.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing it:

```
        boolean useProxy = true;
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions().addArguments(
                '--headless',
                '--no-sandbox',
                '--disable-extensions',
                '--proxy-bypass-list=localhost');
        if (useProxy) {
            options.addArguments("--proxy-server=http://ProxyHost:8080");
        }

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

See https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ for more Chrome switches

Answer (score 0):

Another way to set a proxy:

```
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
    proxy.setHttpProxy("<HOST:PORT>");
    proxy.setSslProxy("<HOST:PORT>");

    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.setCapability("proxy", proxy);

    WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could use proxy was like this

```
String proxy="proxy-server-ip";
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().proxy(proxy).setup();
```