# How to integrate HideMyAss with Selenium tests in JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, vpn

I want to run Java Selenium test from different locations using VPN - HideMyAss. 
I read [How to set proxy for Chrome browser in selenium using Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45288842/how-to-set-proxy-for-chrome-browser-in-selenium-using-java-code)

but I did not find setHttpProxy or setSslProxy URL in HideMyAss account settings. It is even possible ?

[image: VPN settings]

Comment: Does [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56406466/change-proxy-in-chromedriver-for-scraping-purposes/56515662#56515662) helps you?

Comment: No..... It did not